# Displaying Nested Json objects in Admin On Rest In Table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm displaying a list of User IDs, firstNames, lastNames (from a json object named user) and task names (from the json object named workflow) in a datagrid using Marmelab's admin-on-rest.  I know I have to use admin-on-rest's Reference Field but, I'm stuck trying to get a list of task names displayed due to the structure of the "workflow" object. Currently using JSON server to replicate the Backend team's API.

Here is a sample of the workflow object

```
"Workflow": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Example Workflow 1",
      "description": "dolor enim pariatur qui consequat",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "1st Example Task from Workflow 1",
          "descriptions": [
            {
              "viewer": "sunt",
              "instructions": "ex"
            }
          ],
          "viewers": "manager"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "2nd Example Task from Workflow 1",
          "descriptions": [
            {
              "viewer": "pariatur qui dolore",
              "instructions": "voluptate laboris dolore ex laborum"
            }
          ],
          "viewers": "manager"
        }
      ]
    }
```

And the user object

```
"user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "firstName": "Mary",
      "lastName": "Bloody",
      "email": "mary.bloody@example.org",
      "phone": "989-456-2229",
      "type": "employee",
      "manager": "132B5FBE238448B58675DDD7E471D9C6",
      "employees": [],
      "workflow": "1",
      "tasks": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
```

Here is my list component

```
export const WorkflowList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField label ="User Id" source="id" />
            <TextField source="firstName" />
            <TextField source="lastName" />
            <ReferenceField label="Tasks" source="workflow" reference="Workflow">
                {/* Task Names */}
            </ReferenceField>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

I'm assuming that I may have to create my own "Field" Component but that would lead to another question, how can I manipulate "record" and "source" to get what I want? I'm still new to React and Admin-on-rest.

Comment: Just a suggestion: consider transforming (flattening) the API response in the convertHTTPResponseToREST function of your REST client.

Comment: Are you looking for the `ReferenceArrayField`? https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Fields.html#referencearrayfield